# Selenium WebDriver Html bullet

Tags: selenium

how to verify bullet before a sentence through selenium WebDriver?

for example : .Enter login id and password

how to test bullet before the above statement.

Comment: Do you know how to use on the element inspector?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the HTML for the statement mentioned in question is as follows:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2 id="stepone"> Enter login id and password </h2>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2 id="steptwo"> bla bla bla </h2>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can verify if the statement has bullet points by checking if the element (`h2` in this case) has an ancestor with tag `ul` (for unordered list, which gives bullet points). The xpath for such a scenario would be: `//h2[@id='stepone']/ancestor::ul`

Since you haven't mentioned which language you are using, here's the sudo code:

```
VerifyIfBulletsExist()
1  List elem = Find_Elements_By_Xpath("xPath goes here") 
2  if elem.LENGTH > 0
3      pass
4  else fail
```

Comment: how to test a divider in selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0):

This is simple you have to just checked that list contain "Enter login id and password" text.

Steps are:

1 first find all list tags and store it in a list.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagname("li"));
```

2 Then using for each loop navigate to each li tag and verify the text within li tag if li contains text "Enter login id and password" found then bullet.
is verify and test case is passed otherwise test case is failed.

```
int flag =0;
for(WebElement bullet: list){
String bTxt = bullet.getText();
if(bTxt.equalsignorecase("Enter login id and password"))
{
flag =1;
system.out.println("test case passed")}
}
}
if(flag==1){
system.out.println("test case failed")
}
```